# Add total row with sum count

Tags: oracle

I am working with this query:

```
SELECT PAS.NAME, 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CUSOMERS WHERE C_ID = 90
  AND CONTRACT_TYPE = 80
  AND CONTRACT_DATE >= TO_DATE('20160101', 'YYYYMMDD') 
  AND CONTRACT_DATE <= TO_DATE('20161231', 'YYYYMMDD')
  AND ORDER_ID = ORDERS.ID
  AND STATUS = 1
) AS ORDER_SHIPPED_COUNT FROM ORDERS INNER JOIN PAS ON ORDERS.ID = PAS.ID
WHERE ORDERS.COUNTRY = 123 
AND ORDERS.PAYMENT = 30
AND ORDERS.CONTRACT_TYPE = 80
AND PAS.NAME LIKE 'HAS SHIPPED - %';
```

the result I get is the following:

```
NAME                         ORDER_SHIPPER_COUNT
HAS SHIPPED ON TIME          654
HAS SHIPPED LATE             23
HAS SHIPPED AND LOST         2
```

And I would like the result to be like this

```
NAME                         ORDER_SHIPPER_COUNT
HAS SHIPPED ON TIME          654
HAS SHIPPED LATE             23
HAS SHIPPED AND LOST         2
TOTAL                        679
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with t as (
SELECT PAS.NAME, 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CUSOMERS WHERE C_ID = 90
  AND CONTRACT_TYPE = 80
  AND CONTRACT_DATE >= TO_DATE('20160101', 'YYYYMMDD') 
  AND CONTRACT_DATE <= TO_DATE('20161231', 'YYYYMMDD')
  AND ORDER_ID = ORDERS.ID
  AND STATUS = 1
) AS ORDER_SHIPPED_COUNT FROM ORDERS INNER JOIN PAS ON ORDERS.ID = PAS.ID
WHERE ORDERS.COUNTRY = 123 
AND ORDERS.PAYMENT = 30
AND ORDERS.CONTRACT_TYPE = 80
AND PAS.NAME LIKE 'HAS SHIPPED - %')
select *
from t
union all
select 'TOTAL',sum(ORDER_SHIPPER_COUNT) from t;
```

If you get unique records through your query then you may use the below query also without using UNION ALL:

```
with t as (
SELECT PAS.NAME, 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CUSOMERS WHERE C_ID = 90
  AND CONTRACT_TYPE = 80
  AND CONTRACT_DATE >= TO_DATE('20160101', 'YYYYMMDD') 
  AND CONTRACT_DATE <= TO_DATE('20161231', 'YYYYMMDD')
  AND ORDER_ID = ORDERS.ID
  AND STATUS = 1
) AS ORDER_SHIPPED_COUNT FROM ORDERS INNER JOIN PAS ON ORDERS.ID = PAS.ID
WHERE ORDERS.COUNTRY = 123 
AND ORDERS.PAYMENT = 30
AND ORDERS.CONTRACT_TYPE = 80
AND PAS.NAME LIKE 'HAS SHIPPED - %')
select nvl(name,'TOTAL') name,
       sum(ORDER_SHIPPER_COUNT) ORDER_SHIPPER_COUNT
from t
group by rollup(name);
```

Comment: Can you check the second query, if it also works for you.